bindParam (PDO)- SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
I am learning php and getting the error:
"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" when executing below php pdo code. mysql table only have 2 attributes, id and name. I couldn't find the answer googling. PHP version 8.2.12.
$a = 2;
$b = "input to database";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `name`) VALUES (':a',':b');";

$stmt = $connection->prepare ($sql);
$stmt->bindParam (':a', $a);
$stmt->bindParam (':b', $b);

$stmt->execute();

I've tried below and still the code didn't work:

adding or remove colon on the bindParam param
tried below:
$stmt->bindParam (':a', $a, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam (':b', $b, PDO::PARAM_STR);


Remove the quotes from around :a and :b in your query
